# ShiftCipher objects that can encrypt and decode text messages based on a specific shift length

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code should shift the text to a desired number of alphaets to the right of the alphabet:

```
def __init__(self, shift):
        """
        Constructs a ShiftCipher for the specified degree of shift (positive or negative),
        by building a cipher (dictionary mapping from letters to other letters), and 
        a decoder (the inverse of the cipher)
        """
        self.shift = shift
        self.letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        self.cipher = {self.letters[i]: self.letters[i-abs(self.shift) % abs(len(self.letters))] for i in range(len(self.letters))}
        self.decoder = {self.letters[i-abs(self.shift) % abs(len(self.letters))]: self.letters[i] for i in range(len(self.letters))}
        



    def transform_message(self, message, cipher):
        """
        Transforms a message using the specified cipher.  Is not called by users directly,
        and can be called with either the cipher (to encrypt) or the decoder (to decode).
        """
        tmsg = ''
        for c in message:
            tmsg = tmsg + str(cipher.get(c, c))
        return tmsg

    def encrypt(self, message):
        """
        Transforms a message using the cipher, by calling self.transform_message
        """
        return self.transform_message(message, self.cipher)
```

However, for example, I want to encode the following text by 13 alphabets to the right:

```
test = "I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him."
```

The result should be: **V pBzr GB oHEL PnrFnE, ABG GB CEnvFr uvz**.
But I am getting : **v PbZR gb Ohel pNRfNe, abg gb ceNVfR UVZ**
Which means the shifter is shifting to the left 13 times, instead of right.

How do I force it to shift to the right by changing the cipher code?

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of factors. When creating the cipher:

- You subtract the shift value (actually *abs(shift)*) when you should have added it (positive shift should move to the right, negative to the left) so, basically you're actually doing a decrypt

  - I assume that at the beginning you did try to add the shift, but you got an *IndexError*, that you tried to get rid of using (what I consider) this (lame) workaround (*gainarie*): subtract the absolute value. **Here lies the root cause of the problem**:

    - "***%***" (*mod*) has a higher priority than "***-***" (*sub*), so it gets executed 1<sup>st</sup> ([[Python.Docs]: Expressions - Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), and therefore the operation result is different than the expected one
    - *IndexError* doesn't occur when subtracting, because *Python* sequences support negative indexing (from the end)

    Note: Your function would work fine for negative shifts
- To make things even funnier, the chosen shift value (13) is half of the upper / lower alphabets size, so the actual result is expected one but **in switched case**. Another "special" shift value is 26: in that case the encrypted result would be the very input text in switched case

Here's a simplified (and cleaner) variant:

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import string
from pprint import pprint as pp


ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase


def encrypt_orig(text, shift, alphabet=ALPHABET):
    alph_len = len(alphabet)
    mapping = {l: alphabet[i - abs(shift) % alph_len] for i, l in enumerate(alphabet)}
    return "".join((mapping.get(c, c) for c in text))


def encrypt(text, shift, alphabet=ALPHABET):
    alph_len = len(alphabet)
    mapping = {l: alphabet[(i + shift) % alph_len] for i, l in enumerate(alphabet)}  # First add, then mod
    return "".join((mapping.get(c, c) for c in text))


def decrypt(text, shift, alphabet=ALPHABET):
    alph_len = len(alphabet)
    mapping = {l: alphabet[(i - shift) % alph_len] for i, l in enumerate(alphabet)}  # First sub then mod (but here it makes no difference)
    return "".join((mapping.get(c, c) for c in text))


def main(*argv):
    test = "I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him."
    shifts = (13, 10, -20)
    funcs = (encrypt_orig, encrypt, decrypt)
    results = {}
    for shift in shifts:
        print("\nShift: {:d}".format(shift))
        for func in funcs:
            results[func.__name__] = func(test, shift)
        pp(results, sort_dicts=False)
    print("\nDecrypt encrypted text: {:s}".format(decrypt(results[encrypt.__name__], shift)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q069832327]> python code00.py 
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
>
> Shift: 13
> {'encrypt_orig': 'v PbZR gb Ohel pNRfNe, abg gb ceNVfR UVZ.',
>  'encrypt': 'V pBzr GB oHEL PnrFnE, ABG GB CEnvFr uvz.',
>  'decrypt': 'v PbZR gb Ohel pNRfNe, abg gb ceNVfR UVZ.'}
>
> Shift: 10
> {'encrypt_orig': 'y SecU je Rkho sQUiQh, dej je fhQYiU XYc.',
>  'encrypt': 'S mywo Dy lEBI MkoCkB, xyD Dy zBksCo rsw.',
>  'decrypt': 'y SecU je Rkho sQUiQh, dej je fhQYiU XYc.'}
>
> Shift: -20
> {'encrypt_orig': 'o IUSK ZU HaXe iGKYGX, TUZ ZU VXGOYK NOS.',
>  'encrypt': 'o IUSK ZU HaXe iGKYGX, TUZ ZU VXGOYK NOS.',
>  'decrypt': 'c wIGy NI vOLS WuyMuL, HIN NI JLuCMy BCG.'}
>
> Decrypt encrypted text: I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him.
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- Encapsulating everything in a class (like you did) would be beneficial since the ciphers (mappings) would be only computed once (per shift value)
- The decrypt mapping can be computed in either way: by subtracting the shift value, or by reversing the encrypt cipher. In the latter case, it would be simpler: `decrypt_mapping = {v: k for k, v in encrypt_mapping.items()}`
- Play in the *Python* terminal with operations *e.g.*: `5 - 3 % 2` (just to exercise)
- Also, when reaching an impasse, you can debug the code yourself (step by step, or / and *print* all the variables you find relevant)